# How can I both extract a specific line in a text file as well as multiple lines containing a specific string?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a collection of text files containing more data than I need. Each file's first line contains a **comma-separated** string that looks like this:

```
stop_id,stop_code,stop_name,stop_desc,stop_lat,stop_lon,location_type,parent_station,zone_id
```

Then, below those keys is all the data. I need to extract a subset of that data into a new text file so I can work with the subset (I don't need all the data, it's too much).

I'm using this command to extract the first line:

```
sed -n '1p' source.txt > destination.txt
```

I'm also using this command to extract the specific lines I need:

```
grep "string" source.txt > destination.txt
```

The challenge is that when I run the two commands in the same script (pretty much as is, separated by a line or `&&`), the `grep` output overwrites the `sed` output. How can I run both in sequence and have the combined output of both?

I noticed a question that seems similar and involves using a more complex `grep` command to locate the one line, followed by a range of lines. That won't work here because the first line of each of the files I need to extract data from is different.

Ideally, I want to write a function that I can run against each of the files I need to work with but I need to chain these commands and combine their outputs first.

Comment: A simpler command to do the job of `sed -n 1p` would be `head -n 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the `grep` output to append,

`grep "string" source.txt >> destination.txt`

Comment: Ugh! I knew it would be something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`sed` can do both jobs (print first line and all lines containing `string`):

```
sed -n '1p; /string/p' source.txt > destination.txt
```

or longer version:

```
sed -n -e '1p' -e '/string/p' source.txt > destination.txt
```

Comment: Might be worth just adding one or two lines to explain what that does / why it works, to help people in future see if it applies to their problem.

Comment: If `string` is multiple words, I take I wrap those in ""? So something like this?

`sed -n '1p; /"string words"/p' source.txt > destination.txt`

Comment: Yes. It's a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: @PaulJacobson no, no need for quotes, those will be considered part of the pattern. So `/"foo"/` will only match `"foo"` not `foo`. If you have a space, include the space: `sed -n '1p; /string words/p' ` or, if you can have more than one, `sed -n '1p; /string  *words/p' `

Comment: @PaulJacobson: I missed the quotes. Get rid of them. terdon: Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways of doing this. You can use a single command to get both lines, as [@Cyrus's `sed` solution does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413617/22222). Here are a couple of other tools that can do this:

```
awk 'NR==1 || /string/' source.txt > destination.txt
perl -ne 'print if /string/ || $. ==1' source.txt > destination.txt
```

You can of course also run both commands you were running and simply change the second to append to the file [as BANJOSA suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413616/22222). Alternatively, you could group the two commands in a subshel and redirect the subshell's output to a file:

```
(sed -n '1p' file; grep string file) source.txt > destination.txt
```

or

```
{ sed -n '1p' file; grep string file; } source.txt > destination.txt
```

So if what you want to do is make a function out of these, it would be as simple as adding this to your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
foo(){ sed -n '1p' file; grep string file; }
```

And now you can run the function `foo` to do what you want:

```
foo source.txt > destination.txt
```

Comment: +1 but the commands in the function should use `"$1"`  (or `"$@"`) as the file argument, not hard-coded to `file`.